# How to create a Vultr.com-like user interface demonstration

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web, css-transitions, user-experience

In https://www.vultr.com/, they have a frame with a video-like demo of their UI.

**It's not actually video - the text is selectable.**

Is there a specific library used for this?

Answer (score -1):

I whet to they sites, I opened my console and typed `for (let script of document.scripts) console.log(script.src)` to see all scripts running there from external sources. The output is as you see:

```
"https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"
"https://www.vultr.com/dist/js/jquery.min.js?v=250"
"https://www.vultr.com/dist/js/core.min.js?v=250"
"https://www.vultr.com/dist/js/main.js?v=250"
"https://www.vultr.com/_js/global.js?v=250"
""
"https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"
```

then copied the forth URL into another tab, and got the file content which beginning is as follow: (I choose it because it wasn't minified)

```
    $(function()
{
  'use strict';

  handleMainMenu();
  handleResponsiveSidebar();
  handleAccordionMenu();
  handleTooltips();
  handleFloatingLabels();
  handlePackageSwitcher();
  checkBoxes($('body'));

  var animation_offset_px = 200;
  if (typeof onGetAnimationOffsetPx === 'function')
  {
    animation_offset_px = onGetAnimationOffsetPx();
  }
  handlePageAnimations(animation_offset_px);

  if ($('body').hasClass('page-scrollspy')) 
  {
    handleScrollSpySidebar();
  }

  $('.reponsive-image-types > li > a').on('click', function(e) 
  {
     e.preventDefault();
     var imageType = $(this).data('type');
     var imagePreview = $('.responsive-image .browser');
     imagePreview.removeClass('desktop-size tablet-size mobile-size').addClass(imageType);
     $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     imagePreview.find('.control-panel').removeClass('animated');
     setTimeout(function()
         {
       imagePreview.find('.control-panel').addClass('animated');
     }, 1000);
  });
```

And as far as I can see, the `wisdom` of select-ability is defined in that function: (check the source of that script, even `scripts`) there is only 2 occurrences